# Terraform: Reference multiple resources without naming each of them

Tags: terraform

I am creating multiple subnets via a variable:

```
variable "private_subnets" {
      description = "Private Subnets"
      default     = ["10.0.0.0/20", "10.0.32.0/20"]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = element(var.private_subnets, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  count             = length(var.private_subnets)
}
```

I count how many subnets I have listed in my Var and then create a subnet for each. The problem is so far I can only figure out how to reference them by each individual index:

```
subnets          = [ aws_subnet.private[0].id, aws_subnet.private[1].id ]
```

What is the correct way to do this? I tried a similar element() and count section to the ECS network config where I'm referencing this, but it isn't working.

Comment: " ECS network config " - can you show example of that? "but it isn't working" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: If you are looking for list comprehension like in `python` then check out `terraform`  [for expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) and [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are after, but you can try:

```
subnets = aws_subnet.private[*].id
```

This syntax is called [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html)